# Cant push to UnionType array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, typing, union-types

I am playing around with UnionTypes in TS and I thought that I could create a valid scenario where they could be used, but I do not understand why this is breaking with the error of:

> Argument of type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & { name: string; }'

I know ways to "force" this partical approach, but I want to understand why this does not work.

```
let newArray: string[] | { name: string }[] = new Array();

//just a boolean to know when is one type or the other
    if (isMultiple) {
      otherArray.forEach((item: { name: string }) => {
        newArray.push(item)
      })
    }
    else {
      otherArray.forEach((item: { name: string }) => {
        newArray.push(item.name)
      });
    }

    return newArray
```

Comment: What is the type of `otherArray`?

Comment: You can only have 1 type of array at a time here. Your claiming to the ide that it is both. You can solve this by using a typeguard on the arrray after its created. Otherwise you need to create the array inside the if statement

Comment: You really should use `map` here, not `forEach`+`push`

Comment: The type of otherArray is of tpye {name:string}[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant have both types of arrays at the same time. You could do this and define it then create it separately in the if statement

```
let newArray: string[] | { name: string }[];

//just a boolean to know when is one type or the other
    if (isMultiple) {
      newArray = new Array< { name : string }>();
      otherArray.forEach((item: { name: string }) => {
        newArray.push(item)
      })
    }
    else {
      newArray = new Array<string>();
      otherArrayforEach((item: { name: string }) => {
        newArray.push(item.name)
      });
    }

    return newArray
```

Comment: So the issue is that I instantiate newArray with both types at the same time ?

Comment: Yeah the ide has no idea which type its supposed to be when you defined it as either but then instatiate it as just an array you get the error when trying to assign stuff to it. If later on you need to know the type of array it is you can use a typeguard.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to allow mixed arrays (`let newArray: (string | { name: string })[]`), you can use

```
// just a boolean to know when is one type or the other
if (isMultiple) {
  const newArray: { name: string }[] = [];
  otherArray.forEach((item: { name: string }) => {
    newArray.push(item)
  });
  return newArray;
} else {
  const newArray: string[] = [];
  otherArray.forEach((item: { name: string }) => {
    newArray.push(item.name)
  });
  return newArray;
}
```